# Minio: Render images in browser

Tags: browser, object-storage, minio

I'm uploading my svg files to my local minio server (running in docker).

```
const uploadedFile = await client.putObject(bucketName, filename, readStream);
```

I then generate a public URL e.g. `http://localhost:9000/link-identifiers/example.svg` and I can download the files from there publicly

If I want to display it in the browser like `<img src={picUrl}>`, the images don't render at all.

[image]

I get those Response Headers in the browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 124775
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
ETag: "109be6a37b9091e50651b3cbbe6bed3a"
Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 06:44:28 GMT
Server: MinIO/RELEASE.2020-08-07T01-23-07Z
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Request-Id: 1630E4E87DF71408
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2020 06:52:34 GMT
```

Is there any additional configuration for the minio server I need in order to make images render?
If I'm able to download them & and they're perfectly fine (when viewing them), shouldn't they be able to render in the browser too?

Currently the permissions for the bucket are set to `public` with:

```
mc policy set public myminio/link-identifiers
```

Answer (score 5):

The `putObject` function takes in an optional `metadata` argument.

```
  const metadata = {
  'Content-type': 'image',
};
```

Pass it on as an argument to the function to be able to render images.

Comment: this works, thanks :)

Comment: me too, thank's! just added minioClient.putObject.contentType(file.getContentType())...

Answer (score 0):

download mc.exe from this link [minio download](https://min.io/download#/windows)

or click this link [mc. exe](https://dl.min.io/client/mc/release/windows-amd64/mc.exe)

after download
open the command line where mc.exe is and enter this command

```
mc.exe alias set my mini http://192.168.1.101:9000 mini admin mini admin
```

or

```
mc.exe alias set my mini [your mini server URL] [minio username] [minio password]
```

after that, your browser can load images or file like this
[image: like this]